# Untraceable Digital Cash?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I have read some articles regarding digital cash that is untraceable ([Here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.805/articles/money/nsamint/nsamint.htm)). Their protocol is provided below

> Withdrawal:
>
> ```
>  Alice creates an electronic coin and blinds it.
>
>  Alice sends the blinded coin to the Bank with a withdrawal request.
>
>  Bank digitally signs the blinded coin.
>
>  Bank sends the signed blinded coin to Alice and debits her account.
>
>  Alice unblinds the signed coin.
> ```
>
> Payment/Deposit:
>
> ```
>  Alice gives Bob the coin.
>
>  Bob contacts Bank and sends coin.
>
>  Bank verifies the Bank's digital signature.
>
>  Bank verifies that coin has not already been spent.
>
>  Bank enters coin in spent-coin database.
>
>  Bank credits Bob's account and informs Bob.
>
>  Bob gives Alice the merchandise.
> ```

In this protocol Alice sends a blinded message to Bank. Then how does the bank reduce the amount from her account? If that amount is not blinded then what are the other details Alice needs to blind to the bank?

Answer (score 1):

The blinding mechanism blinds a random value. The amount is in the signature, eg the bank uses a key X for a 100$ bill, a key Y for a 200$ bill, a key Z for 300$ bill.
Thus the bank can know the amount by checking which key is used to sign.

Its important that a static value (static for all "bills") is used in the message, else the same coin can be double-spent multiple times by simply spending blinded coins. By using a random static value same for all coins, ensuring coins that is depoisted is really properly unblinded, and one random value that ensures each coin is unique.

Its important that the bank signs ANY coin, but only accepts depoist of coins having a unique static value + random value. This adds a risk for the customer: If the customer does blind a non-coin message and ask bank to sign it for lets say 100$, then those 100$ will be "burnt". Theres no way for the bank to verify if a blinded coin is valid in its unblided state. Same if the customer blinds a already spent coin and withdraws it again, since the same coin can be blinded in unlimited number of variants, and since bank will accept ANY coin for withdrawal, the bank can use the same coin to withdraw 100$ multiple times, but also important that the bank checks that the coin is unblinded Before accepting it for depoist, to preserve the double spend protection.
This means you can withdraw 100$ multiple times with the same coin, but can only depoist the coin once, which means you will "burn" Money in this process too.

To faciliate Exchange, eg you pay a 100$ bill for a 80$ merchandise, you should get 20$ back. For this to work, theres 2 solutions:
The retailer prepares a couple of unminted coins and ask bank to sign for (withdrawing Money from retailer's account), and then gives to customer. However, this requires the customer to trust the retailer, because if the retailer does not intentionally blind the coins, or blinds the coins badly (for example, with a bad random value), then the customer can be traced by the bank.

This can be solved by the customer minting "unminted coin materials" - eg valid but blinded coins which are unsigned, that the customer gives to the retailer. The retailer sends the coin to the bank which signs for them. The retailer gives back those blinded, but signed, coins to the customer, which unblinds then, and depoists them to the bank.

if the retailer and customer does not trust each other, and does not trust the bank either, its possible for the retailer to create a blinded message, which the retailer gives to customer. Customer blinds the coin (again), and then sends to bank for withdrawal. Upon receiving signed coin from bank, the customer unblinds the coin (now the coin is only blinded once), then customer gives coin to retailer, which unblinds the final value, and sends to bank for depoist. Not the retailer and not the customer, can be traced.
This regardless of if retailer or customer omits a blinding step in a attempt to trace the customer or retailer. Both must agree on a traceable transaction for it to occur.

Same is repeated for Exchange, eg customer blinds coins, gives to retailer, blinds a second time, sends double-blinded coin to bank, bank signs, retailer unblinds, customer unblinds, customer sends to bank for depoist.

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot the bank simply deduct Alice's account and add the funds to the Bob's account and delete the log of the transaction?

If the bank creates just a piece of "blinded" information in exchange for debiting Alice's account, then it must keep track of that "coin". If it didn't, then Alice could just copy the piece of digital information and spend it over and over again...

So for the "untraceability" you simply trust that your bank will not keep track of the associations between the coins it issues and the users that ordered creating them...

**EDIT:**

After reading the explanation from sebastian nielsen bellow and more detailed look at the referenced report I see the point of the scheme, which is to provide payer anonymity. Quoting the referenced report:

> The ideal situation (from the point of view of privacy advocates) is
>   that neither payer nor payee should know the identity of the other.
>   This makes remote transactions using electronic cash totally
>   anonymous: no one knows where Alice spends her money and who pays her.
>
> It turns out that this is too much to ask: there is no way in such a
>   scenario for the consumer to obtain a signed receipt. Thus we are
>   forced to settle for payer anonymity.

The provided schemes really ensure that the secure payment is anonymous for the payer, but it doesn't mean that it is untraceable or transferable (all these topics are covered there as well), which I incorrectly assumed.

Comment: No. The bank keeps a double-spending database of the coins. You as a retailer must verify the coin with the bank Before giving away the merchandise.

Comment: Trusting the bank not to keep associations is not required. Since the coin is blinded, any associations will be blinded in the process of unblinding. Bank will sign any coin, but only accept coins with a certain static value + a random value, see further down.

Comment: Banks have to keep records of transactions. The opportunity for error/fraud becomes too high.

Comment: @schroeder: Any error, as I wrote in my answer, is entirely on the customer side, and all errors err on the safe side (eg, causing customer to lose Money), thus are safe from any fraud. The bank can keep a record of all transactions, but will still be unable to tie a withdrawed coin to a depoisted coin. However, the signature prevents fake coins from being minted, and the double-spending database prevents double-spending of the same coin.